# RPC Error: execution reverted

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I am Developing EVoting system as my final year project and i am encountering this error
`RPC Error: execution reverted`

**Voting.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract Voting{
    
    address public owner = msg.sender;

    string myName = "Azid";

    function showData() public view returns (string memory)
    {
        return myName;
    }
   
}
```

**Abi code of Voting.sol:**

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = '0x8aE711544c45157B72B5f32055EC992E9D0EB2F5';

const abi = 
[
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: 'owner',
      outputs: [{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],
      stateMutability: 'view',
      type: 'function',
      constant: true,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x8da5cb5b'
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: 'showData',
      outputs: [{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],
      stateMutability: 'view',
      type: 'function',
      constant: true,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0xbca02ea8'
    }
]

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

When I call owner it works fine but when I call showData it show me the error.

**Register.js:**

```
import voting from '../../voting';

//Creating Register Functional Component
const Register = props =>{
    const check = async () =>{
        console.log("checking");
        const ok = await voting.methods.showData().call();
    }

    //Returning JSX
    return(
        <Aux>
    
            <button onClick={check}>Check</button>
            
        </Aux>
    )
}

//Exporting Register Functional Component
export default Register;
```

Comment: You should post your answer about fixing `const address = '0x8aE711544c45157B72B5f32055EC992E9D0EB2F5';
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smart contract seems right, you're not showing how you call owner but the await seems fine assuming voting has the proper web3 credentials in the voting file.  Try adding a from address and a gas as parameters of the call, for a call the gas will be returned anyways so it should help with troubleshooting

Comment: I was using old deployed address after it's working fine thanks

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to changed my deployed address and after I changed that address it worked fine.